# Merge duplicate values and sum up total in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[{'asset': 'Discovery Fund', 'amount': 100000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'asset': 'Ethical Fund', 'amount': 200000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'asset': 'Foreign Stocks', 'amount': 9350000, 'rating': 'Very High'},
 {'asset': 'Local Stocks', 'amount': 550000, 'rating': 'Very High'}]
```

I'm trying to merge any duplicate values for the rating key and sum up the amounts.
For example, the list above has ratings value as "High", "High", "Very High", "Very High"

Expected result:

```
[
{'amount': 300000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'amount': 900000, 'rating': 'Very High'}
]
```

Please how can I go about this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: PLease provide code that you have tried.

Comment: While you can do it the way you want, you're misusing the various data structures Python provides you. It'd make more sense to format the result as `{'High': 300000, 'Very high': 900000}`. Even better, have you considered using pandas for your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'asset': 'Discovery Fund', 'amount': 100000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'asset': 'Ethical Fund', 'amount': 200000, 'rating': 'High'},
 {'asset': 'Foreign Stocks', 'amount': 9350000, 'rating': 'Very High'},
 {'asset': 'Local Stocks', 'amount': 550000, 'rating': 'Very High'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

output = df.groupby('rating', as_index=False).sum().to_dict('records')

print(output)
#[{'rating': 'High', 'amount': 300000}, {'rating': 'Very High', 'amount': 9900000}]
```

To do this without `pandas` we can use a `loop` over our `list` and `dict.get()` to grab the value, or 0 for key `rating`.

```
output = {}

for _dict in data:
    output[_dict['rating']] = output.get(_dict['rating'], 0) + _dict['amount']

output
#{'High': 300000, 'Very High': 9900000}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks